# Difference in passing by arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

Basically I have 2 function prototypes:

```
void f1(int p[10]);
```

and

```
void f2(int (&p)[10]);
```

Apparently both f1 and f2 takes in an array of size 10, but I would like to know what is the difference between the 2 syntax.

Thanks.

Comment: IMO In the first one p is a copy of the pointer that is passed. In the second it is a reference to the pointer itself.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal In the second there is no pointer, it's simply a reference to an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In first version p is depleted to type pointer. You can pass an array of different size to function. sizeof operator won't work as expected.

In second version, p is a reference to array of size 10. Passing an array of different size would cause compile time error. sizeof operator would work as expected.

Comment: To elaborate, the first one is the same as `void f1(int *p);` , it is a syntax hangover from 1970s C